# bulk add managedby in powershell

Tags: powershell

Im having a problem adding multiple managed by users for distribution groups. The command runs fine, but when i go to check the managed by users in the the distro group the only person that is added is the last person in the list of the csv file. i used this same file to add the members so im not sure why its not working.

This is what im running

```
import-csv "path to file" | foreach {set-distributiongroup -identity "group name" -Managedby $_.name}
```

Anything im doing wrong? Google has not been my friend tonight.

Comment: You're most likely overwriting the attribute ManagedBy every single time. You need to find all the users you want to be managers of the group and then add them all at once. How it could be done depends on your csv-file... Maybe Group-Object could be your friend here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting the existing value every time. The last user in the loop will become the manager.

```
Import-Csv "path to file" | ForEach-Object {
    set-distributiongroup -identity "group name" -Managedby $_.name
}
```

You could either specify all at once

> To enter multiple values and overwrite any existing entries, use the
>   following syntax: value1,value2

[Source: Set-DistributionGroup @ Technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb124955%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx)

Sample:

```
set-distributiongroup -identity "group name" -Managedby (Import-Csv "path to file" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name)
```

Or you could use key-value pairs to add or remove specific users (without replacing all members).

> To add or remove one or more values without affecting any existing
>   entries, use the following syntax: @{Add="",""...;
>   Remove="",""...}.

[Source: Set-DistributionGroup @ Technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb124955%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx)

Sample:

```
set-distributiongroup -identity "group name" -Managedby @{Add=(Import-Csv "path to file" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name)}
```

or

```
Import-Csv "path to file" | ForEach-Object {
    set-distributiongroup -identity "group name" -Managedby @{Add=$_.name}
}
```

All samples are untested.